# Stop Rewrite If Redirected Internally

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current project uses a file structure with a public folder and main entry point (*index.php*) in the project root:

```
root/
  .htaccess
  index.php
  public/
    style.css
```

In order to make it work, I'm using this *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* /public/$0 [END]

RewriteRule . index.php
```

This works fine and if I access `[site]/style.css` it gets loaded properly. Anything else goes to *index.php*.

However I need to use this under Apache 2.2 where the `END` flag is not available. If I use `L`:

```
RewriteRule .* /public/$0 [L]
```

It stops working because on the next iteration the condition doesn't match anymore and I end up with *index.php* handling it again.

How can I simulate the effect of `END`? I tried adding a guard before final redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.+
RewriteRule . index.php
```

But this allows `[site]/public/style.css` to be accessed. I'd like this to be redirected by *index.php* to return a 404. So, in other words, how can I prevent a rewrite if the URL has already been rewritten by the former rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules on Apache 2.2:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* public/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Due to `RewriteCond` last rule will be executed only when first rule hasn't executed at all because Apache sets `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` to `200` after successful execution of an internal rewrite rule.

Comment: Sorry, but wouldn't that allow for `[site]/public/style.cc` to be accessed?

Comment: Do you want all existing files e.g. `[site]/public/style.css`  to be rewritten to `index.php` as well?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question.

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was looking for. Thank you very much!